# VideoJS - Black screen with loading circle safari 6.1.1

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari, quicktime

I am working with Safari 6.1.1 and videojs. I am streaming an MP4 and am having an issue where the black  screen is loaded when I click play with the loading spinner continuously spinning and the time going to 0:04 and then looping back to 0:00. When I show the native controls I am getting the QuickTime controls with a black bar that says Loading...

The odd part is that if I right click on the video and open it in a new tab QuickTime opens the video no problem.

No errors in the console. It works fine in Chrome and the VideoJS homepage works fine in Safari that I am using to test.

Here is how I am setting up the video the {{}} is handlebars that files in the information upon page load.

```
<video id="docViewerVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" width="90%" height="{{height}}px" src="{{contentURL}}">
    <source src="{{contentURL}}" type='{{mimeType}}' />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

And the JavaScript

```
  videojs.options.flash.swf = 'assets/js/videojs/video-js.swf';
  videojs.players = {};
  var videoPlayer = videojs('docViewerVideo');

  videoPlayer.ready(function(){

  });
```

Let me know if more information is needed or if you have any suggestions on things I can try. Thank you very much for looking.

Comment: Could you share a video to test it ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other videos on this website that work properly? If not, check to see that you have the MIME type for MP4 set properly on the server: video/mp4